# GTK+ typecast style for function arguments

Tags: c, gtk

In GTK+ calls, arguments should (but don't have to) be casted from `GtkWidget` to the most specific class needed by the function before passing the argument. For example, sometimes I see

```
some_call(GTK_WINDOW(window));
```

while other times, I see

```
some_call((GtkWindow *) window);
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is a macro that can both test whether the cast is possible and performs the cast. It's GTKs version/attempt of a type-safe cast. You should use that one.

Comment: As I elaborate in the comments to Amarghosh's answer, such casting macros only test whether the cast is possible if GTK+ and co are compiled in their debug mode. If they are compiled in release mode, then they merely boil down to `(GtkWhatever *)somePtr`. Sure, it's a good idea to use the macro _anyway_ so that you can get the checks for free if ever compiling against a debug version of GTK+, but it's worth emphasising that the macro won't save people from shooting themselves in the foot if they're linking to a release version.

Comment: Just to clarify, the type check macro is expanded in your written program. Therefore the comment from "underscore_d" is wrong. It is of course fine  LINKING to a release version of the library (all distributions come with release compiled shared libraries). You still get the full type safety, unless you don't COMPILE to a release version

Answer (score 8):

`GTK_WINDOW` is a macro that does the cast.

[As seen here](http://www.koders.com/c/fid846104DF1BD38CE6B6060ADF6E09F6B1B2894CFC.aspx?s=tree)

```
#define GTK_WINDOW(obj)  (GTK_CHECK_CAST ((obj), GTK_TYPE_WINDOW, GtkWindow))
```

[Again](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-Types.html)

```
#define GTK_CHECK_CAST G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST
```

[and](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/unstable/gobject-Type-Information.html)

```
#define G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST(instance, g_type, c_type) (_G_TYPE_CIC ((instance), (g_type), c_type))
```

[which is...](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libgobject-2.0-ddefs.html)

```
#define _G_TYPE_CIC(ip,gt,ct)    \
    ((ct*) g_type_check_instance_cast ((GTypeInstance*) ip, gt))
```

The code for `g_type_check_instance_cast` [can be found here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#DQwufpYNS80/openvms/GLIB2_VMSPATCH.TAR|vEOi2zALqkg/glib/gobject/gtype.c&q=g_type_check_instance_cast&l=3136)

```
GTypeInstance*
g_type_check_instance_cast (GTypeInstance *type_instance,
                            GType          iface_type)
{
  if (type_instance)
    {
      if (type_instance->g_class)
        {
          TypeNode *node, *iface;
          gboolean is_instantiatable, check;

          node = lookup_type_node_I (type_instance->g_class->g_type);
          is_instantiatable = node && node->is_instantiatable;
          iface = lookup_type_node_I (iface_type);
          check = is_instantiatable && iface && type_node_conforms_to_U (node, iface, TRUE, FALSE);
          if (check)
            return type_instance;

          if (is_instantiatable)
            g_warning ("invalid cast from `%s' to `%s'",
                       type_descriptive_name_I (type_instance->g_class->g_type),
                       type_descriptive_name_I (iface_type));
          else
            g_warning ("invalid uninstantiatable type `%s' in cast to `%s'",
                       type_descriptive_name_I (type_instance->g_class->g_type),
                       type_descriptive_name_I (iface_type));
        }
      else
        g_warning ("invalid unclassed pointer in cast to `%s'",
                   type_descriptive_name_I (iface_type));
    }

  return type_instance;
}
```

Comment: The specifics of this answer are out of date, but the general idea is probably similar... in debug mode. That's the point: To be at all complete, this answer should clarify this useful but obese type checking is - mercifully for anyone wanting a responsive GUI - only done when building in debug mode, else they do a basic `(Cast *)`: "_If GTK+ and GNOME are compiled with widget debugging disabled, as with a distribution release, the casting macros do only a straight C-style cast, without the overhead of a GTK+ type check and logging message._" http://openbooks.sourceforge.net/books/wga/gtk.html

Comment: Specifically: `_G_TYPE_CIC` is what ultimately gets `#define`d different based on the build mode of GTK+ and co.

Answer (score -3):

GTK_WINDOW() is simply a macro that would look something like this:

```
#define GTK_WINDOW(a) ((GtkWindow*)a)
```

This is identical to doing an explicit cast by yourself, and the two statements you should in your post are identical.

Comment: This is only true when GTK+ and co are compiled in release mode. If they are instead compiled in debug mode, the type-checking routine shown in Amarghosh's answer is performed. So each of you drew half of the picture. If only someone had done both!